# Raspberry: overwrite a file called neam.py from an USB driver to raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cp, usb-drive

I have to overwrite a file called `beam.py` from an usb drive connected to a raspberry, using command line. The raspberry is linked to the tv with hdmi cable. The code that I have to use is:

```
cp [source root] [destination root]
```

but how do I know the directory of the USB drive connected to the raspberry? How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `media file`. Your USB drive will be listed there.

Comment: If i writ lsusb I can look the USB drive, called "SanDisk". Now, I need to discover the directory of "SanDisk", how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cp /media/[username]/[USB_drive_name]/beam.py [destination]
```

If you `cd /media` you would see a folder of your username and then get into that directory and you will find your `USB drive` do a `cd` command to get into your USB drive and then apply the `cp` command

Comment: Using CD i discoverered the path /media/usb1
I wrote:
cp /media/usb1/beam.py nfcpy/trunk/examples/beam.py
response:
cp: cannot stat '/media/usb1/beam.py': no such file or directory
Why? please, help me

Comment: assuming your nfcpy folder is in home directory try `cp /media/usb1/beam.py /home/[username]/nfcpy/trunk/examples/beam.py` give the absolute path to your nfcpy folder starting from root `/`